# Pickling asyncio tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

For a large set of coroutines, I am trying to pickle *done* and *todo* tasks periodically. Sample code is given below:

```
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import random
import time

from typing import Callable, Coroutine

async def coro():
    dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0,15))
    return df

async def todo_tasks():
    for i in range(500):
        todo.add(asyncio.create_task(coro(), name = 'coro'+str(i)))

async def progressAsync(algo: Callable[...,Coroutine],
                       timeout=2) -> None:
    
    task = asyncio.create_task(algo(), name=algo.__name__)
    
    todo.add(task) # add task to the asyncio loop
    
    start = time.time()
    
    while len(todo):
        
        # checkpoints at timeout
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(todo, timeout=timeout)
        
        # remove done task from todo after timeout, update result and pickle it
        todo.difference_update(done)
        result.update(done)
        
        # ...the following does not work!!!
        with open('./result.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(list(result), f)
        
        with open('./todo.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(list(todo), f)
            
        # report pendings
        pending_names = (t.get_name() for t in todo)
        print(f"{len(todo)}: "+ " ".join(sorted(pending_names))[-75:])
        
    # success!
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Took {int(end-start)} seconds")
    
todo = set()
result = set()

asyncio.run(progressAsync(algo=todo_tasks))
```

The program runs well, except for the portion in the *pickle.dump* portion. It gives: `TypeError: cannot pickle 'coroutine' object`.

Is there a way to save/pickle the results temporarily? Intent is to restart progressAsync for the remaining todos and use result for additional processing separately.

Comment: No, you can't pickle asyncio tasks. What you can do is pickle the data which will allow you to rebuild the tasks. It's hard to tell how difficult that is in your use case, since the example you provided is probably significantly different from what you're actually doing.

Comment: @user4815162342: Yes. This is just a sample and use case is significantly complex, with dicts and dfs in the `result`. Resolved the issue by putting a function that spews out the data from the result and pickles it at timeout for the checkpoint.